# input type="number" addClass on increase removeClass on decrease

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

In an online game, students are asked "How many 12-year-olds already have (…)" and have to choose how many of 25 people's icons (4%) they color in. This is actually kind of a range input, but I thought it could be done easily with an input type="number" too.

I've already got it working to some extent. Arrow up or mouse up adds the necessary class, but the remove class doesn't work yet. When I enter a number, the people's icon with that number gets the class, but all icons with a lower id should also get the class.

You can find the live example [here](https://www.aanstokerijserver.be/vad/mannetjesLager.html). The code I'm using:

**HTML:**

```
<svg id="manneke1" class="manneke" (…) /></svg>
(…)
<svg id="manneke25" class="manneke" /></svg>
<input type="number" id="inputMannekes" class="form-control text-center" name="inputMannekes" value="0" min="0" max="25"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.manneke {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#004f75;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-width:11.49px;
}

.gevuld {
  fill:#f5c1bc;
  stroke: #e66557;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#inputMannekes").change(function () {
    if (this.getAttribute('value') === this.value) {
        $(this).data('lastvalue', this.value);
        console.log(this.value);
    } else {
        if (this.value > $(this).data('lastvalue')) {
            $("#manneke"+$(this).val()).addClass("gevuld");
        } else {
            $("#manneke"+$(this).val()).removeClass("gevuld");
        }
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: Why 2 change() calls?

Comment: I think your logic is not correct: if you type a `6` inside the input field, rather than using the increment/decrement arrows, only the sixth image get colored, instead of the first six.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to store the value in the data attributes (`$(this).data(...)`) when you can use variables `let myVariable = ...`. I'm not sure what exactly you were trying to accomplish with this. Also you want to iterate over all the icons because the number may not change by just one (for example, user can directly type 25  into the input).

I see that you used jQuery, but the solution can be easily done with native JavaScript. That's why I'm attaching a sample without jQuery.

```js
// code just for this example (create 24 svgs)
const iconsCount = 25;
const svg = document.querySelector('.manneke');
const root = document.querySelector('.root');
for (let i = 0; i < iconsCount - 1; i++)
  root.append(svg.cloneNode(svg));
  
// code for class replacement
const svgs = document.querySelectorAll('.manneke');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
  // for each icon...
  for (let i = 0; i < iconsCount; i++) {
    // ...add or remove className?
    i < e.target.value 
      ? svgs[i].classList.add('gevuld')
      : svgs[i].classList.remove('gevuld')
  }
});
```

```css
.manneke {
  width: 30px;
  fill:none;
  stroke:#004f75;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-width:11.49px;
}
.gevuld {
  fill: #f5c1bc;
  stroke: #e66557;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <svg class="manneke" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 253.49 384.48"><path class="cls-1" d="M240.77,192.85,180,132s-9.73-11.86-25.49-11.86a60.57,60.57,0,1,0-55.43,0C83.27,120.17,73.54,132,73.54,132L12.72,192.85a23.81,23.81,0,0,0,33.67,33.67l24-24V354.92a23.82,23.82,0,0,0,47.63,0v-86h17.43v86a23.81,23.81,0,1,0,47.62,0V202.51l24,24a23.81,23.81,0,0,0,33.68-33.67Z"></path></svg>
</div>
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="25"/>
```

Comment: Hi Jax-p,
This works, thanks.
In the previous example [link](https://aanstokerijserver.be/vad/mannetjesLager.html) there was a button that onclick showed the solution (3 mannekes). With your new method of creating the svg mannekes, that button no longer works. How do I adjust that? I should just create 3 mannekes with class solution (different color than filled) onclick on top of the input mannekes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#inputMannekes").change(function () {
    for(var i=1; i<= $(this).val(); i++) {
         $("#manneke" + i).addClass("gevuld");
    } 
    for(var i=$(this).val() + 1; i<= 25; i++) {
         $("#manneke" + i).removeClass("gevuld");
    }
})
```